# How are these geometry nodes called in Blender 3.0? Or maybe you know a better way to achieve something like this (diamond on something)?

Tags: node-editor, geometry

How are these geometry nodes called in Blender 3.0?
[image: How are these geometry nodes called in Blender 3.0?]

Or maybe you know a better way to achieve something like this (diamond on something)?
[image: Toilet]

Comment: Check this tutorial. It descript Blender 3.0 geometry node. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4WAxMI1QJMQ

Answer (score 2):

The *Point Distribute* node has been replaced by the *Distribute Points on Faces* node.

The *Point Scale* node has been replaced by the *Set Point Radius* node.

The *Attribute Randomize* node has been replaced with the *White Noise Texture* node.

The *Point Instance* node has been replaced with the *Instance on Points* node, and now allows you to set rotation and scale within the node.

Comment: Thank you. I got this partly working... One thing - rotation. Do you maybe know how to make items face (rotation) out of the model instead of facing one direction? It was made by default in 2.93 but in 3.0 I guess I have to set something in order to achieve this.

Nevermind; connected 'Distribute Points on Faces' rotation to 'Instance on Points' rotation and I think it's working.